# event for automatic reply in outlook like OnNewMessageCompose

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The OnNewMessageCompose event is fired On composing a new message (includes reply, reply all, and forward)...

We would want to do some custom modification in an add-in ...when the automatic reply setting is clicked to set ooo message.

Or

It would be helpful to have a **onAutomaticReplySet** event just like the others in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch#supported-events

Please let us know if there exists an alternative to it via add-ins or com add-ins or office.js etc

Answer (score 1):

> when the automatic reply setting is clicked to set ooo message

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you could do is to check the properties set during the `onSend` callback. Also you may consider using Graph API to fill the gap with add-in features and events.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: but the user setting ooo message & the onsend getting called can be too late...

Comment: For e.g. the ooo message could be set for 15th of the month on the 1st of the month by the user....but we wan't to do some custom activity on the 1st of the month right when the user was setting ooo

Comment: The Microsoft Graph API uses a webhook mechanism to deliver change notifications to clients. For mail items you can use this mechanism to handle such changes.

Comment: is automatic reply a mail item ?

Comment: Have you tried using Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

We don't support that event as part of our Launch Events extension point.  You can submit an idea [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform/label-name/Office%20Add-ins%20development).